# Connect QDomNode with QStandardItem

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom-node

So im working on simple xml reader, and i want to show xml on the tree.

So to get iformation about which item on the tree is wich item in xml file i made a QMap:

```
QMap<QDomNode*,QStandardItem*> connectDomNodeAndStandardItem;
```

but it seems that `QDomNode` create whole new structure of objects when I use any of its method:

```
QDomNode *node = &_xmlDocument.firstChild();
qDebug() << node;
node = &node->firstChild();
qDebug() << &node->parentNode();
```

Output:

```
0x41be60
0x41be28
```

So my question is - How i can connect `QDomNode` with `QStandardItem`

Comment: If I were you I'd change the implementation to something else -- Qt's XML module is no longer actively maintained and is quite buggy.

Comment: Good point, anyway i changed the way of implementantion and done this quite simple XML editor for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDomeNode` is a class that uses explicit sharing. That means all copies of the same node operate on same data. So you don't have to use pointers. And the reason for the different address is because [`QDomNode::parentNode`](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/xml/dom/qdom.cpp.html#_ZNK8QDomNode10parentNodeEv) returns a copy of the parent.